# Atualizando Tabela

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou com um formulário que recebe todos os dados do banco de dados e tem a opção de excluir tal dado desejado. Queria saber se existe alguma forma que quando o usuário clicar no Excluir a pagina já se atualizaria com a nova tabela.

Comment: Pesquise na rede por "[Ajax + php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Ajax+%2B+php)". Provavelmente irá encontrar uma par de resultados que podem te ajudar a resolver o problema

Comment: Sim, haveria. Realizando a sincronização via ajax ou axios.

Comment: `code`ssssssssssssssssssss`code`